# UIWebView increases font size if there's more text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Hello
I am trying to display two different html pages through the same UIViewController which has a UIWebView subview.

Both html pages use the same css and are similar in structure. However, I have noticed that when viewed both in iOS Simulator and on device, the font size of the page that has less content is considerably smaller than of the one that has more content.

Can someone explain to me what I could do to have the same font size on both views?

Here's my UIWebView code:

```
CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
self.webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: appFrame] autorelease];
self.webView.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
self.webView.scalesPageToFit= YES;
self.webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.resourceName ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *urlLocation= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlLocation]];
self.view = self.webView;
```

Here's the associated html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4 /loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<LINK href="manual.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>My Info text</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table >
        <tr>
         <td class="title">
              <b>How to do it</b>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td class ="content">
          Some Instructions on how to do it properly.
         </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS. The main problem seems to be td.content, as the title is sized properly (or at least not visibly different between both screens):

```
body {
background-color : rgb(255,255,255);
font-size : 35px;
font-family : Helvetica;
color : rgb(54,54,54);
margin-right : 0px;
margin-left : 0px;
}

table {
width : 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-top : 20px;
margin-bottom : 20px;   
margin-right : 0px;
margin-left : 0px;
border-spacing : 0px;
padding-right : 0px;
padding-left : 0px;
}

tr {
margin-top : 0px;
margin-bottom : 0px;    
margin-right : 0px;
margin-left : 0px;
}

td.content {
font-size : 1em;
text-align : left;
vertical-align: top;
margin-top : 0px;
margin-bottom : 0px;    
margin-right : 0px;
margin-left : 0px;
padding-top : 5px;
padding-bottom : 10px;
padding-right : 30px;
padding-left : 30px;
}

td.title {
width : 170px;
font-size : 1.5em;
font-weight : bold;
text-align : left;
vertical-align : top;
margin-top : 0px;
margin-bottom : 0px;    
margin-right : 0px;
margin-left : 0px;
padding-top : 5px;
padding-bottom : 10px;
padding-right : 30px;
padding-left : 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting to scalesPageToFit property?

```
[myWebView setScalesPageToFit:NO];
```

You've set it to YES which might affect how it decides to zoom in to the page?

(taken from [the docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Comment: If I set it to NO, both views display a huge font size and the texts extend far beyond the screen which is not what I want either.

Comment: So set the body's width to be 320px in your css and make the font smaller :) Your font is set to 35px - that's pretty big - it's just doing what you told it to!

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 buttons - A- and A+

```
    @interface
NSUInteger textFontSize;

- (IBAction)changeTextFontSize:(id)sender

    switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 1: // A-
            textFontSize = (textFontSize > 50) ? textFontSize -5 : textFontSize;
            break;
        case 2: // A+
            textFontSize = (textFontSize < 160) ? textFontSize +5 : textFontSize;
            break;
    }

    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", 
                          textFontSize];
    [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
    [jsString release];
}
```